# Maven: How to Add JPA Project in EAR using Pom.xml

Tags: maven, jpa

How can I add JPA Project in the EAR pom.xml file? I don't see the JPA Module in the Maven.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
                <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What do you mean by JPA module?

Comment: eg: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html ejbClientModule
ejbModule
webModule

Comment: You can use simply a jar module...